# MySQL using REPLACE INTO with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Is it possible where one table has to be updated and other one inserted from one query? or I am dreaming?

I used query

```
REPLACE INTO 
    ASSET_ASSOCIATION, 
    ASSET_HISTORY
JOIN 
     ASSET ON ASSET.ID = ASSET_ASSOCIATION.ASSET_ID
JOIN 
     HD_TICKET ON HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE2 = ASSET.NAME
JOIN 
     HD_TICKET_CHANGE ON HD_TICKET_CHANGE.HD_TICKET_ID = HD_TICKET.ID
JOIN 
     USER U ON U.ID = HD_TICKET.SUBMITTER_ID
SET 
     ASSET_ASSOCIATION. ASSOCIATED_ASSET_ID = ( 
         SELECT 
             A.ID 
         FROM 
             ASSET A 
         WHERE 
             U.FULL_NAME LIKE BINARY CONCAT('%',A.NAME,'%') 
         AND 
             A.ASSET_TYPE_ID = 8 AND A.NAME <> ''),
     ASSET_HISTORY.TYPE_NAME = 'Computer', 
     ASSET_HISTORY.ASSET_ID = ASSET.ID, 
     ASSET_HISTORY.NAME = ASSET.NAME, 
     ASSET_HISTORY.TIME = NOW(), 
     ASSET_HISTORY.CHANGE_TYPE = 'Modification', 
     ASSET_HISTORY.FIELD_NAME = 'FIELD_46', 
     ASSET_HISTORY.VALUE1 = HD_TICKET_CHANGE.USER_ID, 
     ASSET_HISTORY.VALUE2 = HD_TICKET.SUBMITTER_ID, 
     ASSET_HISTORY.FRIENDLY_FIELD_NAME = 'User'
WHERE 
     HD_TICKET_CHANGE.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Changed ticket Submitter%'
AND 
     ASSET_ASSOCIATION.ASSET_FIELD_ID = 46 
AND 
     ASSET.ASSET_TYPE_ID = 5
AND 
     HD_TICKET.ID = <TICKET_IDS>
ORDER BY 
     HD_TICKET_CHANGE.TIMESTAMP DESC
LIMIT 1
```

It is full of error and very buggy but just to give you an idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather look at

`INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Not sure if this allows to actually manipulate two tables, but perhaps could be achieved through `VIEW`.

Comment: Is there a way to do join in the above statement?

Comment: The INSERT part is normal insert, so you can do INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...